# Content Type Subscriber has its last run = N/A

Tags: 2013, content-type, central-administration, configuration, content-type-hub

I tried to publish some content types inside my site collection hub, but the content types were not published correctly, as they did not appear under custom content types at the other site collections. now i checked Content Type Subscriber status and it showed its last run =N/A as follow:-

[image]

Now i checked the "Content type publishing error log" under the site collection hub , but it did not show any errors .

and when i checked the Content Type hub job , i find that the web application is set to N/A, as follow, although the managed metadata is connected to the web application :-

[image]

so can anyone advice how i can fix this problem ?

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but are your timer job service actually up and runnig?

Comment: @RobertLindgren yes it is running.. and i restart it but did not fix the problem. i did iisreset, restart the whole server.. now when i first create the site collection and i publish my first CT it was published correctly. but when i update the CT the i republish did not work, also now if i add new CTs they will not be showing in the other site collections...so not sure what is going on ?

Comment: @RobertLindgren can you adivce what i can do to fix this ?

Comment: Check here about detatching the service application from your webapp, wait a few minutes and then attach it again http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20871/content-type-not-showing-up-after-publishing-to-hub-what-am-i-doing-wrong

Comment: @RobertLindgren thanks for the link but this will not solve the problem..

Comment: @RobertLindgren now i created a new site collection , and i find that the content type will be published inside it,,, but for the old site collection the CT did not show ,,,

Comment: New ones do not use this timer job for what I know, it is used for updating existing ones

Comment: @RobertLindgren now the timer job is started inside my services,, so not sure if it is causing the problem,, i think the main problem is that the "Content Type Subscriber" has its last run as N/A.. if i can fix this i think every thing will work fine.. so what i need to do about this ? how i can check if the timer job is causing the problem ?

Comment: John, I'm not the only user here. I have given you what i know and that seems to not be enough.

Comment: i noted something is that even the schedule search job will not start ,,so seems there is somethings wrong ..

Comment: Just an idea, but maybe you could go to Central Admin, Application Management, Manage Content Databases... Select your Web Application, and click on the Content Database....

From within there, you can set a "preferred" timer job server.

It might help.