# Problem with timer jobs not being scheduled

Tags: timer-jobs, 2016, custom-timer-job

I had setup a new 2 server SP 2016 Farm and was having a problem with most of the Timer Jobs (to include my custom timer jobs) not being scheduled and showing "N/A" for their last run time.

I had googled and found a few ways to try and remedy this problem.  Some of them suggested to restart the timer service on each server, turn on verbose logging and inspect the ULS logs for errors and [change the user the timer service runs as](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/602660-microsoft-sharepoint-foundation-workflow-timer-service-starting).  A few questions were asked [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149413/content-type-subscriber-has-its-last-run-n-a) and [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20871/content-type-not-showing-up-after-publishing-to-hub-what-am-i-doing-wrong), but were never answered.  The comments had things to try, but were never answered.  After a few days of troubleshooting, none of these ideas worked.

Can someone help me resolve why the timer jobs are not being run?

My Farm setup is:  Server 1 - Front-End role with Central Admin and Distributed Cache.  Server 2 - Front-End role.

Answer (score 0):

A PFE suggested that I try and change the server role configuration.

I rebuilt the farm with Server 1 as Application role with Central Admin and Server 2 with Front-End role and Distributed Cache.

This role configuration change was the trick to get the Timer Jobs (to include my custom timer jobs) scheduled and working as they were intended.  The N/A went away and were replaced with the Last Time they were ran.